# fl.motion cannot be found with Flex SDK 4.1

Tags: actionscript, flex4

I just upgraded to using version 4.1 of the Flex SDk and FlashBuilder.

Now, whenever I try to import the fl.motion library, like so

```
import fl.motion;
```

I get the following error:

1172: Definition fl.motion.easing could not be found

Has anyone else encountered a similar error?

Answer (score 11):

The fl package is only available as part of Flash CS3 or higher so you'll need to add them to your FlashBuilder project library path yourself.

If you have Flash CS3 or higher, the fl package swc's and source can be found within the app folder scattered around in `Common/Configuration`.  For fl.motion, try `Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/libs/flash.swc` (that's where mine were for CS4 on the mac).  Other classes such as UI controls are elsewhere.

Some people have also made a swc available containing everything in case you don't have a Flash CS IDE.  This [post](http://evolve.reintroducing.com/2007/10/30/tips-n-tricks/fl-package-swc/) has a swc available.

Answer (score 3):

For Flash CS6, copy this swc:
/Applications/Adobe Flash CS6/Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/libs/flash.swc

Into your Flash Builder project using these steps:
http://interactivesection.files.wordpress.com/2009/06/include_fl_packages_in_flex_builder-1.jpg